# Not receving email notification in Gmail Inbox when someone shares Google sheet with me

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, email-notifications, google-drive-shared-drive

I mostly work in a circle where users share their Google sheets with me for collaboration. But for some days, I am not receiving any email notifications for Google sheets that are shared with me. It is very disturbing for me as sometimes it delays my response to the user because I am not notified that someone shared the Google sheet with me.

```
drive-shares-dm-noreply@google.com
```

I checked the above email in Gmail, and it is not in spam folder or blocked. Still, I am clueless why notifications are not coming to my Gmail inbox. Kindly can anyone guide me about it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Notification settings for Google Sheets have 2 ways of being modified, the first one is in [`Drive`](https://drive.google.com/) where you can allow the notifications of new shared files to be sent to your Email as stated in this [documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6318501). This is how the setting looks:

[image]

The second way is by modifying within Google Sheets service, and you do so from the tools menu following this [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/91588), this is what you can modify:

[image]

If all of the above has been set up already and you are under a Google Workspace domain I'll recommend [contacting support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213) as it may be an Admin console issue.